# Which one is more efficient, multiple dictionary or class instance?

Tags: python

I'm making a card name. Each card have its own attribute. I'll make at least thousands of cards. And I need to examine the relationship between card attributes. I'm wondering which kind of style will have better performance? Here are my two plans.

```
# style 1
card_dict = {card1:{val1: content, val2: type, val3: {...}, ...}

# style 2
class card(object):
    def __init__(self,content,type,val3):
        self.val1 = content
        self.val2 = type
        self.val3 = val3

card1 = card(content1,type1,val3)
card2 = card(content2,type2,val3)
```

Comment: the best performance for which operations? You need context

Comment: If using IDE then class approach is better because then IDE can helps you on which attributes class has (also it is better for readability).

Comment: I mean to retrieve the value of each card. The processing time. kind of stuff @UmNyobe

Comment: don't think of processing time if it's not really a problem. Think of readability and ease of understanding.

Comment: Both boil down to O(1) operations (hash table lookups, in fact).

Comment: remember that class attributes are stored in a dictionary - in other words, they are basically the same thing, decorated two different ways. however, you can store class attributes in `__slots__`, which will save memory if you're generating a lot of them.